# Webpack config doing nothing in codesandbox project

Tags: webpack, codesandbox

I've created this codesandbox example which has a `webpack.config.js` and has `webpack`/`webpack-cli`/`webpack-dev-server` installed as dependencies. Except it's not being used. I can delete a random part of the config so that it shouldn't run/compile, but codesandbox will still run as if the webpack config didn't exist.

How can I get this project to actually use webpack?

https://codesandbox.io/s/chakra-ui-default-dark-mode-forked-2eilh?file=/webpack.config.js

I've tried different permutations/variations upon `scripts` inside `package.json` to no avail. This was one attempt:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "dev": "webpack serve",
  },
```

If it were on my local machine, I'd use `npm run dev` to build it.